# Creating Aspect bean in Spring Java Config file causes another bean to not be autowired

Tags: junit, mockito, spring-aop, spring-java-config

Having a weird issue with attempting to test a Spring AOP class.

Here is a similar setup since I cannot put the actual code on here.

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyTestConfiguration.class})
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService1 myService1;

    @Autowired
    private MyService2 myService2;


    @Test
    public void testAop() {
        myService1.methodToBeIntercepted();
        verify(myService2).create();
    }
}
```

Spring Java Configuration File:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Configuration
public class MyTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyService1 myService1() {
        return new MyService1Impl();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyService2 myService2() {
        return Mockito.mock(MyService2.class);
    }
}
```

AOP Class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAop {
    @Autowired
    private MyService2 myService2;

    @Around("execution(* package.MyService1.methodToBeIntercepted(..))")
    public void interception(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {

       // do stuff

       MyReturn myReturn = (MyReturn) joinPoint.proceed();

       myService2.create();
    }
}
```

With this setup I get an error saying that the test wanted 1 execution of myService2.create() but there was none. This means the AOP class is not intercepting the call properly and that the Spring configuration is correct in that all beans are found.

Next I added the following to MyTestConfiguration to create the bean for the AOP class:

```
@Bean
public MyAop myAop() {
    return new MyAop();
}
```

Now I get a Spring error saying it can't find the MyService1 bean so the test never runs. Simply adding the myAop bean to MyTestConfiguration now causes the MyService1 bean to no longer be recognized by Spring.

Am I doing something wrong and if so, what?

Comment: Which error exactly do you get in your first scenario? How can you call verify on a non-mock object?

Comment: That was my bad. I changed MyService2 to a mock in the Config file. The error I am receiving first is that the mocked service was never called.